# Drawing a line in OpenCV with CV_AA flags is not producing an anti-aliased line

Tags: opencv

I am unable to get cv::line to draw an anti-aliased line with CV_AA flags set.  Here is example code to illustrate:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat base(100, 100, CV_32F);

    cv::Point2i p1(20, 20);
    cv::Point2i p2(70, 90);

    cv::line(base, p1, p2, cv::Scalar(1.0), 1, CV_AA); // 1 pixel thick, CV_AA == Anti-aliased flag

    cv::namedWindow("line test", CV_NORMAL);
    cv::imshow("line test", base);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried using cv::Point2d instead of cv::Point2i and found no difference. (i == integer, d == double)  I have also tried making the pixel width larger than 1, but there is still no AA.

However, this does work with a CV_8U (8-bit unsigned) image, as opposed to CV_32F (32-bit float) image that I have here.  (For CV_8U, you must pass cv::Scalar(255) instead of cv::Scalar(1.0) into the line function to compare)

I suppose a current work-around would be to start with a CV_8U image then convert, but is there a straightforward way to do it with just an CV_32F image that doesn't require me to write my own anti-aliasing function?

Am I missing something?

OpenCV docs: [cv::line reference](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=line#line)

Comment: It may be a problem in OpenCV, but I want to point to you a strange piece of code: you can move the cv::namedWindow and cv::imshow outside loop, keeping the same functionality for much better speed.

Comment: Ah, yeah, good point.  I threw that together for the question.

Comment: actually, you can write c = cv::waitKey(); return 0; When you press a key, waitKey() will return and close the program.

Comment: Yes, but you can't resize the image with the mouse cursor and get a closer look of the line, then.  That was the purpose behind the loop.  An alternative is to use the threaded version of the window, but I wanted to keep this simple.

Comment: Hm, I tried it and you can still resize the window that way.  So, you were right.  For other applications where you usually pass a number > 0 into cv::waitKey, like showing a video, it doesn't work, as there are no more updates after the allotted time.  I don't remember that being there in the past.  Modified the code as you suggested.

Answer (score 12):

```
./core/src/drawing.cpp:1569
void line( Mat& img, Point pt1, Point pt2, const Scalar& color,
       int thickness, int line_type, int shift )
{
    if( line_type == CV_AA && img.depth() != CV_8U )
        line_type = 8;
    //omitted
}
```

The source code states that as long as the depth is not CV_8U, it will draw using 8-connected method.

Comment: so are there any ways to use CV_AA in non-CV-8U images?

Answer (score 7):

Can you provide a sample image? I also tried it myself and it's working perfectly fine with this code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::zeros(500, 500, CV_8UC3);

  // red line, which is not anti-aliased
  cv::line(img, cv::Point(100, 100), cv::Point(400, 105), cv::Scalar(0,0,200), 3, 4);  

  // green line, which is not anti-aliased
  cv::line(img, cv::Point(100, 200), cv::Point(400, 205), cv::Scalar(0,200,0), 5, 8);

  // blue line, which is anti-aliased
  cv::line(img, cv::Point(100, 300), cv::Point(400, 305), cv::Scalar(200,0,0), 10, CV_AA);

  cv::namedWindow("drawing", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE|CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO);
  cv::imshow("drawing", img);

  cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

That'y my outcome:
[image]

Comment: This is an AA line, and what I get when setting the base image to CV_8U: http://imgur.com/4wlea . This is a non-AA line, and what I get when setting the base image to CV_32F, despite CV_AA being passed into the cv::line function: http://imgur.com/MSogk .  You are using a CV_8U image in your example.  I want the function to work for CV_32F.