# Drawing line with thickness become white, OpenCv iOS issue

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, drawing, line

I'm developing an iOS app using the OpenCV framework,
the problem occurs when I try to draw something in my outputframe.

In the image below I'm trying to draw a line and a circle

```
    cv::circle(outputFrame, startingPoint, 50, cv::Scalar(250,0,250), -1);
    cv::line(outputFrame, startingPoint, endpoint, cv::Scalar(0,250,0),4);
```

The problem occurs when I increase the thickness of the line the line itself became white with a contour of green " color green = cv::Scalar(0,250,0)"

Any help is appreciated

[image: The image representing the problem]

Answer (score 0):

[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055837/drawing-a-line-in-opencv-with-cv-aa-flags-is-not-producing-an-anti-aliased-line)

The reason you are getting a white contour with green color is - it just behave as single contour with both circle and line. It doesn't get segmented.

Comment: No, maybe I did not explain well.
Whether I drawing lines with the green outline and thickness> 2.0 or drawing circles still have the problem that the thickness is colored white.