# cv2.LINE_AA does not render antialised edges

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to draw a polygon using `cv2.fillConvexPoly`. I was expecting to get anti-aliased edges with the flag `lineType=cv2.LINE_AA` on. But seems it does not do the work.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot(2, 3, 1)
mask = np.zeros((80, 50), dtype=np.float32)
polygon_arr = (np.array([[10, 16],[26, 20],[31, 50],[14, 50]])).astype(np.int32)
cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, polygon_arr, 1, lineType=cv2.LINE_4)
plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray')
plt.title('1, LINE_4')

plt.subplot(2, 3, 2)
mask = np.zeros((80, 50), dtype=np.float32)
polygon_arr = (np.array([[10, 16],[26, 20],[31, 50],[14, 50]])).astype(np.int32)
cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, polygon_arr, 1, lineType=cv2.LINE_8)
plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray')
plt.title('1, LINE_8')

plt.subplot(2, 3, 3)
mask = np.zeros((80, 50), dtype=np.float32)
polygon_arr = (np.array([[10, 16],[26, 20],[31, 50],[14, 50]])).astype(np.int32)
cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, polygon_arr, 1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray')
plt.title('1, LINE_AA')

plt.subplot(2, 3, 4)
mask = np.zeros((80, 50), dtype=np.float32)
polygon_arr = (np.array([[10, 16],[26, 20],[31, 50],[14, 50]])).astype(np.int32)
cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, polygon_arr, 255, lineType=cv2.LINE_4)
plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray')
plt.title('255, LINE_4')

plt.subplot(2, 3, 5)
mask = np.zeros((80, 50), dtype=np.float32)
polygon_arr = (np.array([[10, 16],[26, 20],[31, 50],[14, 50]])).astype(np.int32)
cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, polygon_arr, 255, lineType=cv2.LINE_8)
plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray')
plt.title('255, LINE_8')

plt.subplot(2, 3, 6)
mask = np.zeros((80, 50), dtype=np.float32)
polygon_arr = (np.array([[10, 16],[26, 20],[31, 50],[14, 50]])).astype(np.int32)
cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, polygon_arr, 255, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray')
plt.title('255, LINE_AA')

plt.show()
```

[image]

I tried different `lineType` flags but they seem to produce identical results. I also tried alternating the `dtype` to `int32` but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the result images with parameter value LINE_8 and LINE_AA for comparison?

Comment: Can you try to draw with color value 255 instead of 1? I guess that the anti aliasing now interpolates between 0 and 1 integer values which is rounded to either 0 or 1..

Comment: Thank you so much! I updated the code and figure. The results seem all identical regardless of 1 or 255 or what lineType is used.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Drawing a line in OpenCV with CV_AA flags is not producing an anti-aliased line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055837/drawing-a-line-in-opencv-with-cv-aa-flags-is-not-producing-an-anti-aliased-line)

Set the `dtype` of original image to `np.uint8` solves the problem.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mask = np.zeros((80, 50), dtype=np.uint8)
polygon_arr = (np.array([[10, 16],[26, 20],[31, 50],[14, 50]])).astype(np.int32)
cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, polygon_arr, 255, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray')
plt.title('1, LINE_AA')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the link. I'm voting to close the question **as a duplicate** of the one you found.